# Mahalanobis distance in VBA

Tags: vba, statistics, mahalanobis

I am trying to calculate Mahalanobis distances in VBA.

I have created my UDF to calculate Covarince matrix but i got a #value error when executing my function.

could you give me some help

Thanks in advance!

```
Function DMahalanobis(x As Range, y As Range) As Variant
    Dim c() As Variant, k As Variant, U As Range, a() As Variant, b() As Variant
    Set U = Application.Union(x, y)
    Debug.Print U
    k = x.Columns.Count
    a = x
    b = y
    ReDim c(1, k)
    For i = 1 To k Step 1
        c(1, i) = a(1, i) - b(1, i)
    Next i
    DMahalanobis = Application.MMult(Application.MMult(Application.Transpose(c), Application.MInverse(MVARCOVAR(U))), c)
End Function
```

This is my VarCovar function that works fine

```
'Function to calculate Covariance matrix
Function MVARCOVAR(RANGO As Range) As Variant
Dim c() As Variant, i As Long, k As Long, j As Long
k = RANGO.Columns.Count
Debug.Print k
ReDim c(k, k)
 For i = 1 To k Step 1
  For j = 1 To k Step 1
  c(i, j) = Application.Covar(Application.Index(RANGO, , i), Application.Index(RANGO, , j))
  Next j
 Next i
MVARCOVAR = c
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: The first thing to do when you write a UDF is to make it work as a normal function by testing it within a macro. Does it?

Comment: you use `a()` and `b()` without defining them. You `ReDim c(k)` but you use it as two-dimensional array...

Comment: @A.S.H I have corrected  the issues you have mentioned , nevertheless i continue to get #value Error. Is there anything else wrong?

Comment: Are you feeding it with row ranges or column ranges? Please provide an example with ranges and data if possible.

Comment: `ReDim c(1 To 1, 1 To 5)`... probably wont solve it but to have all our arrays same dimensions. Anyway it'll be extremely difficult to debug such a formula `DMahalanobis = `, you should split it in parts to see what part doesnt work.

Comment: @A.S.H I am feeding it with row ranges, I have generated 3 columns with certain distribution (Triangular distribution) as dummy variables.

Comment: Remove ` Debug.Print U`, it's blocking there.

Comment: in MVARCOVAR, `ReDim c(1 To k, 1 To k)`

Comment: I have achieved my code to work , nevertheless I am facing the problem of non-invertibility of covariance matrix

Comment: same here, The matrix you are getting is not invertible I dont know why :S

Answer (score 1):

may due to the singular issue in the line:

```
DMahalanobis = Application.MMult(Application.MMult(Application.Transpose(c), Application.MInverse(MVARCOVAR(U))), c).
```

Based on your given input, dimension of `U` is `2xk`, as `2<<k`, the covariance matrix of U may contain some missing value, when you take the inverse, it will pop up an error. Maybe you can try to change `U` to the whole data set, otherwise you cannot capture the distribution information in the data when calculating mahalanobis distance.